# How can I copy a particular file from a source directory to a destination directory while recreating the folder structure

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have to use batch only . The destination folder should have the copied file along with the directory structure of the source directory (for the file copied only). Example :

Source: C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\text1.txt
Destination: C:\backup

After the command is executed The destination folder should look like :
C:\backup\folder1\folder2\folder3\text1.txt

I must use the command from C:\ (root directory) only .
In my source there are multiple files with name ="text1.text" ,but with different folder structure. I want only that "text1.txt" to be copied whose path i am providing (source), and not all files named "text1.txt" [this can be achieved using--- xcopy Source\text1.txt* Destination /S /Y].PLease help.

Comment: How/where are the paths to process (or the excluded paths) specified? You could create a batch that visits all subdirectories and executes a copy command for every not-excluded subdirectory. F.e., I´ve created batches like this to copy a tree branch, skipping all directories that contain a special "excludeme!" marker file in the process, solely using dir, copy, if and for.

Comment: That can be archieved by "dir /S /B, catch the input, and iterate over the resulting names using for. There, for every directory, execute a batch or command that performs 'if markerfile is NOT present, copy all files (but no subdirs) of this directory to the target'". The biggest catch there then are the evil for syntax, banks in directory and file names, and long file names, all of which can be solved using double quotes and other tricks from the command-line help of for, dir, if, and copy.

Comment: i need a batch which accepts input as : C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\text1.txt (parameter 1) C:\backup(parameter 2)  ... I donot have special "donot copy me" markers.

Comment: is there any xcopy comand that can do this ?

Comment: Do you want a `BATCH` or do you wanr an `XCOPY` command? You've said both in your last two comments.

Comment: if Xcopy can achieve this then i can use it.Otherwise batch .

Comment: "folder should look like :
C:\backup\folder1\folder2]folder3\text1.txt" you mean, with that bracket inside?

Comment: Sorry for the "[". It should look like ---C:\backup\folder1\folder2\folder3\text1.txt"

Comment: All I am asking is that , is there a way to preserve the folder structure from the source to destination while copying a particular file ?

Comment: @user2074474 yes, using xcopy as you stated, but then you won´t be able to specify exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: This command alone will accomplish the task using ONLY XCOPY
:: BUT I'm changing the directorynames to suit my system
::
XCOPY c:\sourcedir\a\b\text1.txt u:\backup\sourcedir\a\b\
::
:: Or leave the last XCOPY out and this batch will do the same
:: if you supply the parameter "c:\sourcedir\a\b\text1.txt"
::
:: IE. at the prompt, enter
::
:: thisbatchname "c:\sourcedir\a\b\text1.txt"
::
:: (where the quotes are optional UNLESS the parameter contains 
::  a special character or a space"
::
XCOPY "%~1" "u:\backup2%~p1"
```

The first XCOPY should be obvious.

The second works by using `%~1` which is the first parameter, minus the enclosing quotes (if any) - this is then requoted to ensure the character string produced is parsed as a single string.

The second parameter to XCOPY strings `U:\BACKUP2` together with `%~p1` - which is the `p` - PATH of parameter 1, then quote the whole thing.

Consequently, the command executed with `"c:\sourcedir\a\b\text1.txt"` as a parameter would be

```
xcopy "c:\sourcedir\a\b\text1.txt" "u:backup2\sourcedir\a\b\"
```

which creates the destination tree as required.

Comment: very appropriate, you should put some help text inside your capital batch. :)

Comment: Wow. So it took us that many comments to understand that to specify a specific target location, you specify that location as the target location. Sigh.

Comment: I believe deleting the `x` from every entry of `xcopy` wouldn't change anything. :)

Comment: @Andriy M But it will. XCOPY will generate the path. COPY won't